# PHP: Is it possible to modify varibles of an included php file?

Tags: php, variables, include

I am new to php.
I have a header.php with variables which I want to be uniquely set depending on which php page includes the header.php. I want each page that loads the header to display unique data in the header - current page info.
Currently I have something like the following:

header.php

```
     <?php $pageInfo = "";?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/header.css">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header-box">
            <div id="header-wrapper">
                <div id="logo-box">
                </div>
                <div id="info-box">
                    <div>
                        <p><?php echo $pageInfo ?></p>                      
                   </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

page1.php

```
<body>
    <div><?php $pageInfo = ":D"; require 'shared/header.php'; ?></div>
    <div><?php include 'shared/menu.php';?></div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes, that's doable. include/require'd files are treated as if they were literally cut&paste into the spot where the include/require call is. so you're effectively using some "global" variables.

Comment: Hi Marc B. Thank you for your response.  What you said is good news. However, the code I provided above is not working. Nothing is being displayed. Either the variable wasn't truly modified or something else is wrong.

Comment: because at the top of your header file, you set $pageInfo to be empty, so it'll ALWAYS be empty elsewhere in the header.

Comment: Oh. Now I understand. Thank You Marc B and Vivek Sancheti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible. Include works like as you have have merged multiple pages (Scripts) into one. So if you want to change the value of variables in header.php before including header.php define them.

ex:

```
<?php 
$pageInfo  = 'Test page';
require_once 'header.php';
?>
```

Note: Do not declare $pageInfo = '' in header.php else it will over write it. You can do as follow in header.php:

```
if(!isset($pageInfo)) {
 $pageInfo = '';
}
```